# Getting to Olkhon Island in late September

Tags: russia, irkutsk, baikal

I am traveling to Irkutsk, Russia in late September and would like to get to Olkhon Island (Khuzhir). I have checked the following boat and bus schedules:

- https://vsrp.ru/en/passengers/timetable/
- https://avtovokzal-on-line.ru/

And it appears as though there is no transportation in late September—but it could also be that they have not updated / don't display the winter season yet.

What is the best way to travel to Olkhon in late September?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the VSRP hydrofoils stop running as soon as the tourist season is over in late August, per WayToRussia the bus+local ferry combo keeps operating until Lake Baikal freezes over completely in December.

https://waytorussia.net/Baikal/Destinations/Olkhon.html

I found the avtovokzal bus schedules to be 100% accurate last month (not really surprising, since you can also buy tickets online), so I'd suggest keeping an eye out -- they'll publish the new schedule sooner or later.